# Spring-ldap jar is missing in central maven starting from version 1.3.2

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-ldap

I couldn't find the **spring-ldap** jar in central maven starting from version 1.3.2.

We use maven to manage dependency and we pull the spring jars from central maven (in turn using an internal repository)because this jar is not available in central maven we are not able to pull it. Please advice why this jar is missing in Maven central and what alternate options are available?

Even in spring repo(https://repo.spring.io/release) the artifact are provided as a zip file and the jar isn't provided directly.

**Looking for the below artifact** 
Group ID: org.springframework.ldap
Artifact ID: spring-ldap
version: 2.0.2

Comment: Please, show your pom.xml dependency for this jar that is missing

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Did you include repo.spring http://repo.spring.io/release/ repository to your pom?

Comment: Yes, even in repo.spring.io/release the jar is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The best option, as for me, is to use needed submodules of spring-ldap, for instance spring-ldap-core:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring-ldap-core is in different version and spring-ldap is in different version. spring-ldap jar is a module by itself right?